# Can External Objects be packaged in Managed Packages?

Tags: managed-package, externalobjects, 2gmp

The [Metadata Coverage Report][1] doesn't mention if External Objects can be packaged as part of Managed Packages.

So, this is not clear if External Objects can be packaged in Managed Packagesor not?
[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/53/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, External Objects can be included in Managed Packages both 2GMP and Classic Packages (1GMP).

This can be verified by creation of 1GMP or 2GMP and including unathenticated External OData 2.0 Endpoint https://orderdb.herokuapp.com/orders.svc and Order and Order Details external objects.

I was able to package external data source and related External Objects as both 1GMP and 2GMP.

They are listed in Metadata Coverage as Custom Objects.

Since External Data Sources can be included, they can be included as well.

However, this might not be a good approach to deliver this as a package, since some customers who didn't buy the Salesforce Connect feature, will not be able to install such package.